# Alternative to ifelse for three options

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

So I have a database with football(soccer) results. I have a column with difference between home and away team and want to create a column which tells whether the home team won, lost or drew.

So I wrote an if-else statement

```
if (difference>0) {
  result2 = 'win'
} else if (difference<0) {
  result2 = 'loss'
} else if (difference==0) {
  result2 = 'draw'
} else {
  result2 = 'error'
}
```

Howerver, this if-else statement is not possible since if is not vectorized in R. And when I use ifelse() I can only have two outcomes, so only win or loss for example. Is there a simple way to overcome this problem?

Comment: `df$NewVar <- ifelse(df$difference>0,'win',ifelse(df$difference<0,'loss',ifelse(df$difference==0,'draw','error'))`

Comment: FYI, in R `if` is *also* an expression — so you’d usually write `result = if (difference > 0) 'win' else if (difference < 0) 'loss' else if (diference == 0) 'draw' else 'error'` instead of repeatedly assigning to `win`.

Comment: Use `sign` to index an outcome vector: `c("loss", "draw", "win")[sign(difference) + 2]`

Answer (score 1):

With `data.table`, we can use `fcase`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, result := fcase(difference > 0, "win",
                             difference == 0, "draw",
                               default = "lose")]
```

Answer (score 0):

`dplyr` package has a function `case_when()`:

```
difference <- sample(-1:1, 10, replace = T)
difference
# [1]  1  0 -1  0  1  0 -1 -1 -1 -1

winlose <- case_when(
  difference > 0 ~ "win",
  difference == 0 ~ "draw",
  TRUE ~ "lose" # Default value if none of previous conditional holds
)
winlose
# [1] "win"  "draw" "lose" "draw" "win"  "draw" "lose" "lose" "lose" "lose"
```